# Calculate separate No of Week and Days between 2 Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate weeks and days between 2 Dates, Like that
IN SQL QUERY

if  Date from : 10-01-2018  Date to : 19-01-2018

so i want the result "1 week and 2 days"

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: I am using SQL server management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL (Transact-SQL) you can use the datediff-method:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

whic in your case would be

```
DATEDIFF(day,10-01-2018, 19-01-2018);
```

And then divide the days with 7 and take the remainer as days.

More info at [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @From   datetime
DECLARE @To datetime

SET @From ='20180110'
SET @To ='20180119'

SELECT  DATEDIFF(ww,@From, @To) AS Week,
DATEDIFF(dd,@From, @To)%7   AS  Days
```

Comment: @naveedahmed check this now

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATEDIFF` function with `datepart=day`.
The number of weeks is the result divided by 7 and the number of days is the remainder